# What are the benefits of using MVC 3 framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We have started a new Asp .net web project. We plan to do in in MVC. Is it a good practice to use Microsoft's MVC 3 tool or is it good to define our own structure? Web site requirements are normal. Some people suggest if we use microsoft tool we will loose our control in the project????? Any problems that we may face when we use micosoft MVC 3 tool (Razor)?

Comment: Please reword your question. **"Is it a good practice to use Microsoft's MVC 3"**, **"Web site requirements are normal"**. I mean come on, seriously.

Comment: What I mean is no special requirements and Do we need to use the MVC 3 tool from Microsoft or we define our own MVC structure? Some team members suggest not to use MVC 3 tool from micosoft and define our own structure for MVC(means create normal ASP .net web application and create folders for model view and controller and continue from there)?

Answer (score 0):

no really, there isn't any problem -present and future; if you have deep knowledge about issues such as OOP, ASP.NET structure and how it works, MVC architecture, etc. I suggest you strongly use and enjoy ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to MVC then I would suggest go through basic (or advance dependending upon how much you know) MVC tutorials before deciding arch. Things can be done in various ways and it differs from project to project. Once you build your knowledge about things like DomainModel, serviceLocator, IoC, ViewModel, Helpers, repository pattern etc. you will have better idea about which tool to use. I would start looking at some of the sample projects on the codeplex. (would not be too hard to find)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If I said yes, would you go ahead and use it? The same goes for building a house or working on any project. What has worked for me, might not work for you. I would start from reading learning resources on [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc). I would also suggest reading about HTTP protocol and its stateless nature as well as looking at differences between web forms and mvc frameworks. Good luck.